# What is the use of defining a method as its own class data type?

Tags: java, android, class, android-sqlite

When I was learning SQLite database in android, there was a method to open the database and its datatype was its own Class! But there is method named close in the same class to close the database but with void datatype.

Can anyone help me to understand the use of Class data type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From this [doc](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html),We can know `openXXX` method return `SqliteDatabase` because your next operation will use the database object to operate,like query,insert and so on.However after `close` is invoked,you won't use the database anymore,so it need't to return such type.

And normally we use [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) instead.